# how to encoding email address inside email content

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 8.

I want to sending reset password link. but when I want to append email address to token as parameter:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('.....')
        ->action('Reset', url('password/reset', $this->token.urlencode('&email='.$notifiable->email)))

}
```

the result of email content is:

```
http://****/password/reset/326e15aad30c49acc55d39ff6983ccf33a838311b48c00318bc23e1a354b2c5b%2526email%253DS.M_Emian%2540yahoo.com
```

this output cannot decode from javascrpit.

Comment: What is it exactly that you are expecting? What is the desired output?

Comment: @BrianThompson  updated

Comment: You're misusing `urlencode` I believe. You need to encode the content of `&email` not `&email=some content` so what it should be is `$this->token . '&email=' . urlencode($notifiable->email)`

Comment: IMO, email isn't required. You need to hit a DB request to fetch the email from the token row in the DB and place it inside a hidden input field

Answer (score 0):

You can send the Password Reset link using the existing functionality in Laravel 8 as [documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords#password-reset-link-handling-the-form-submission)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

$status = Password::sendResetLink(
    $request->only('email')
);
```

More info about [Password reset](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords)